# How to return a table by checking entries in a assosiated table and if child table doesnt exists return the parent table anyway

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am currently using sequilize and not sure how I would run this query. I want to return the table either if the entry exists and meets certain parameters in the child table or just return the entry if the child table doesnt exist.

```
 const users = await this.doctorsRepository.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        first_name: {
          [Op.or]: [
            { [Op.like]: `%${primary}%` },
            { [Op.like]: `%${nameSplit[0]}%` },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        last_name: {
          [Op.or]: [
            { [Op.like]: `%${primary}%` },
            { [Op.like]: `%${nameSplit[1]}%` },
          ],
        },
      },
      { specialty: { [Op.like]: `%${primary}%` } },
    ],
    // [Op.or]: [
    //   {
    //     '$userRegistered.email_verified$': {
    //       [Op.or]: [null, 0],
    //     },
    //   },
    //   {
    //     '$userRegistered.doctor_verified$': {
    //       [Op.or]: [null, 0],
    //     },
    //   },
    // ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'userRegistered',
      // where: {
      //   [Op.or]: [
      //     {
      //       email_verified: {
      //         [Op.or]: [null, 0],
      //       },
      //     },
      //     {
      //       doctor_verified: {
      //         [Op.or]: [null, 0],
      //       },
      //     },
      //   ],
      // },
    },
    {
      model: UserMap,
      where: userMapWhere,
      include: [
        {
          model: DoctorLocation,
          required: location ? true : false,
          where: locWhere,
          attributes: [
            'city',
            'address',
            'name',
            'postal_code',
            'state',
            'full_address',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'primary',
          ],
        },
        {
          model: DoctorDetail,
          attributes: ['suffix', 'image_url', 'health_center', 'specialty'],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  subQuery: false,
});
```

I have tried using something like this

```
        [Op.or]: [
      {
        '$userRegistered.email_verified$': {
          [Op.or]: [null, 0],
        },
      },
      {
        '$userRegistered.doctor_verified$': {
          [Op.or]: [null, 0],
        },
      },
    ],
```

it works however the query is really slow not sure how would I get the same result without query taking forever.

Here is the generated SQl;

```html
Executing (default): SELECT `DoctorBio`.`index`, `DoctorBio`.`first_name`, `DoctorBio`.`last_name`, `DoctorBio`.`health_center`, `DoctorBio`.`userId`, `DoctorBio`.`specialty`, `DoctorBio`.`is_active`, `DoctorBio`.`load_date`, `userRegistered`.`id` AS `userRegistered.id`, `userRegistered`.`role` AS `userRegistered.role`, `userRegistered`.`firstName` AS `userRegistered.firstName`, `userRegistered`.`lastName` AS `userRegistered.lastName`, `userRegistered`.`about` AS `userRegistered.about`, `userRegistered`.`medical_school` AS `userRegistered.medical_school`, `userRegistered`.`medical_school_year` AS `userRegistered.medical_school_year`, `userRegistered`.`residency` AS `userRegistered.residency`, `userRegistered`.`residency_year` AS `userRegistered.residency_year`, `userRegistered`.`email` AS `userRegistered.email`, `userRegistered`.`password` AS `userRegistered.password`, `userRegistered`.`password_last_change` AS `userRegistered.password_last_change`, `userRegistered`.`prefix` AS `userRegistered.prefix`, `userRegistered`.`health_center_id` AS `userRegistered.health_center_id`, `userRegistered`.`health_center` AS `userRegistered.health_center`, `userRegistered`.`location_name` AS `userRegistered.location_name`, `userRegistered`.`telephone` AS `userRegistered.telephone`, `userRegistered`.`doctor_db_id` AS `userRegistered.doctor_db_id`, `userRegistered`.`email_verified` AS `userRegistered.email_verified`, `userRegistered`.`email_verification_token` AS `userRegistered.email_verification_token`, `userRegistered`.`doctor_verified` AS `userRegistered.doctor_verified`, `userRegistered`.`profile_completed` AS `userRegistered.profile_completed`, `userRegistered`.`twoAuth` AS `userRegistered.twoAuth`, `userRegistered`.`isAvailable` AS `userRegistered.isAvailable`, `userRegistered`.`profile_picture_url` AS `userRegistered.profile_picture_url`, `userRegistered`.`verify_profile_url` AS `userRegistered.verify_profile_url`, `userRegistered`.`createdAt` AS `userRegistered.createdAt`, `userRegistered`.`updatedAt` AS `userRegistered.updatedAt`, `userRegistered`.`deletedAt` AS `userRegistered.deletedAt`, `userMap`.`index` AS `userMap.index`, `userMap`.`userId` AS `userMap.userId`, `userMap`.`health_center_id` AS `userMap.health_center_id`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`index` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.index`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`city` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.city`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`address` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.address`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`name` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.name`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`postal_code` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.postal_code`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`state` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.state`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`full_address` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.full_address`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`latitude` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.latitude`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`longitude` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.longitude`, `userMap->doctorLocation`.`primary` AS `userMap.doctorLocation.primary`, `userMap->doctorDetail`.`index` AS `userMap.doctorDetail.index`, `userMap->doctorDetail`.`suffix` AS `userMap.doctorDetail.suffix`, `userMap->doctorDetail`.`image_url` AS `userMap.doctorDetail.image_url`, `userMap->doctorDetail`.`health_center` AS `userMap.doctorDetail.health_center`, `userMap->doctorDetail`.`specialty` AS `userMap.doctorDetail.specialty` FROM `scraped_user_final` AS `DoctorBio` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `userRegistered` ON `DoctorBio`.`userId` = `userRegistered`.`health_center_id` AND (`userRegistered`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) INNER JOIN `user_map` AS `userMap` ON `DoctorBio`.`userId` = `userMap`.`userId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `agg_locations_enriched` AS `userMap->doctorLocation` ON `userMap`.`health_center_id` = `userMap->doctorLocation`.`health_center_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `agg_detailed_bio` AS `userMap->doctorDetail` ON `userMap`.`health_center_id` = `userMap->doctorDetail`.`health_center_id` WHERE ((`DoctorBio`.`first_name` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `DoctorBio`.`first_name` LIKE '%Addiction%') OR (`DoctorBio`.`last_name` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `DoctorBio`.`last_name` LIKE '%Medicine%') OR `DoctorBio`.`specialty` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%') LIMIT 1, 20;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `role`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `about`, `medical_school`, `medical_school_year`, `residency`, `residency_year`, `email`, `password`, `password_last_change`, `prefix`, `health_center_id`, `health_center`, `location_name`, `telephone`, `doctor_db_id`, `email_verified`, `email_verification_token`, `doctor_verified`, `profile_completed`, `twoAuth`, `isAvailable`, `profile_picture_url`, `verify_profile_url`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `deletedAt` FROM `users` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `User`.`id` = 9);
Executing (default): SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`firstName`, `User`.`lastName`, `User`.`about`, `User`.`medical_school`, `User`.`medical_school_year`, `User`.`residency`, `User`.`residency_year`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`prefix`, `User`.`health_center_id`, `User`.`health_center`, `User`.`location_name`, `User`.`telephone`, `User`.`doctor_db_id`, `User`.`email_verified`, `User`.`doctor_verified`, `User`.`twoAuth`, `User`.`isAvailable`, `User`.`profile_picture_url`, `User`.`createdAt`, `User`.`updatedAt`, `User`.`deletedAt`, `specialties`.`id` AS `specialties.id`, `specialties`.`class` AS `specialties.class`, `specialties`.`specialty` AS `specialties.specialty`, `specialties`.`user_id` AS `specialties.user_id`, `specialties`.`createdAt` AS `specialties.createdAt`, `specialties`.`updatedAt` AS `specialties.updatedAt`, `specialties`.`deletedAt` AS `specialties.deletedAt`, `address`.`id` AS `address.id`, `address`.`user_id` AS `address.user_id`, `address`.`city` AS `address.city`, `address`.`formatted_address` AS `address.formatted_address`, `address`.`full_address` AS `address.full_address`, `address`.`is_primary` AS `address.is_primary`, `address`.`latitude` AS `address.latitude`, `address`.`longitude` AS `address.longitude`, `address`.`name` AS `address.name`, `address`.`postal_code` AS `address.postal_code`, `address`.`state` AS `address.state`, `address`.`telephone` AS `address.telephone`, `address`.`createdAt` AS `address.createdAt`, `address`.`updatedAt` AS `address.updatedAt`, `address`.`deletedAt` AS `address.deletedAt` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT OUTER JOIN `specialties` AS `specialties` ON `User`.`id` = `specialties`.`user_id` AND (`specialties`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `addresses` AS `address` ON `User`.`id` = `address`.`user_id` AND (`address`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) WHERE (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND ((`User`.`firstName` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `User`.`lastName` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `specialties`.`specialty` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%') AND (`User`.`id` != 9 AND `User`.`id` IS NOT NULL) AND `User`.`email_verified` = 1 AND `UIN `addresses` AS `address` ON `User`.`id` = `address`.`user_id` AND (`address`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) WHERE (`User`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND ((`User`.`firstName` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `User`.`lastName` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%' OR `specialties`.`specialty` LIKE '%Addiction Medicine%') AND (`User`.`id` != 9 AND `User`.`id` IS NOT NULL) AND `User`.`email_verified` = 1 AND `User`.`doctor_verified` = 1 AND `User`.`isAvailable` = 1));
```

Here are the tables

DoctorRepository

```html
export class DoctorBio extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  index: number;

  @Column
  first_name: string;

  @Column
  last_name: string;

  @Column
  health_center: string;

  @Column
  userId: string;

  @Column
  specialty: string;

  @Column
  is_active: number;

  @Column
  load_date: Date;

  @HasMany(() => UserMap, {
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    as: 'userMap',
    sourceKey: 'userId',
  })
  UserMap: UserMap;

  @HasOne(() => User, {
    foreignKey: 'health_center_id',
    as: 'userRegistered',
    sourceKey: 'userId',
  })
  userRegistered: User;
}
```

UserRepository

```html
export class User extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  id: number;

  @Column
  role: Role;

  @Column
  firstName: string;

  @Column
  lastName: string;

  @Column
  about: string;

  @Column
  medical_school: string;

  @Column
  medical_school_year: number;

  @Column
  residency: string;

  @Column
  residency_year: number;

  @Column
  email: string;

  @Column
  password: string;

  @Column
  password_last_change: Date;

  @Column
  prefix: string;

  // @Unique
  @ForeignKey(() => DoctorBio)
  @Column
  health_center_id: string;

  @Column
  health_center: string;

  @Column
  location_name: string;

  @Column
  telephone: string;

  @Column
  doctor_db_id: number;

  @Column
  email_verified: Status;

  @Column
  email_verification_token: string;

  @Column
  doctor_verified: Status;

  @Column
  profile_completed: boolean;

  @Column
  twoAuth: boolean;

  @Column
  isAvailable: boolean;

  @Column
  profile_picture_url: string;

  @Column
  verify_profile_url: string;

  @HasMany(() => Address, 'user_id')
  address: Address;

  @HasMany(() => Specialties, 'user_id')
  specialties: Specialties;

  @HasMany(() => Fellowship, 'user_id')
  fellowships: Fellowship;

  @HasMany(() => Insurance, 'user_id')
  insurances: Insurance;

  @HasMany(() => Staff, 'user_id')
  staffs: Staff;

  @HasMany(() => Favorites, 'doctorId')
  favorites: Favorites;

  @HasMany(() => Favorites, 'favoriteId')
  favoritesOff: Favorites;
}
```

Comment: Leading wildcards on `LIKE` is slow because it cannot use any index.  For further discussion, please provide the _generated_ SQL.

Comment: @RickJames thank you for the response. At the moment I am not too sure what else to use for a close match espically with name and all. Do you have a suggestion what else I can use instead of like. 

I have updated the question witht the generated SQL

Comment: Please post your table schema.  To speed it up, you need to have some conditions in the where clause which will use one or more indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the SELECT queries.  However, they are not machine-readable because the spaces are gone, replaced by `<code>` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @RohitGupta added both user and doctor models.

Comment: @RickJames so sorry updated it to be in the code block. I hope that is what you are looking for I tried using the other method however due to the use of ` cant seems to get it all in